# Move Access Web Database to Another Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

I have an Access web database (the out-of-the-box Project one) and plan to move to another Sharepoint site (a test server).  I have done lots of googling and nothing comes up.  Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After some trials and errors, I figured out how to do that.  First open the Access web db in Access client.  Then go to Publish & Save, where you should see an option Save As Local Database.  Then open the local database, again go to Publish & Save, you can choose to Publish to Access Services.  A pane will appear to let you enter the URL of Sharepoint server and site name.  If you have customizations or lots of lookups, there's a good possibility it will not publish.  If that's the case, you just need to fix all the errors reported.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move my Access 2016 app to a new Sharepoint Site by saving it as a .app and uploading it to the new site.

I found this link to Microsoft's site helpful: [Create an Access app package](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Access-app-package-5c409c03-ded9-4a41-82c3-fdd490a91b42?CorrelationId=a4bd6816-ed09-4e7b-97e1-d7a7c5d479bc&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)