# View Access Database From Browser

Tags: html, ms-access

I am in need of some help, here is what i have...I have build a Access Database using 2013 and have placed it on our company network.  The database is updated frequently of visitors signing in and out.  What i am trying to do is view the database like a report or select* from table1 (something like that)  I would like to view this by HTML from browser (file://) as i will be using a IPAD that is connected to our network.  I am looking for some insight our other possible ways this might work

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Million-$$$ question: "What is your HTTP Server"?  If your server is IIS, I would recommend writing some ASP.Net/ADO.Net code to "wrap" access to ... MS-Access. I would discourage direct "file://" access to some .mdb file posted on a web server, if at all possible.

Comment: Just a question about the ASP.Net would i use visual studio to create ASP.Net code.  Sorry still pretty new with is so i appreciate the help

Comment: If your organization had a Sharepoint server available, that would be easier than IIS.  If you were going to use IIS, then yes, you'd probably use MSVS.  In most cases, giving users direct access to the physical .mdb file is probably a Bad Idea.  Even then, they could only update the .mdb from a file share (they're physically on the LAN, or connected with a VPN).  Using a web app - or better, using Sharepoint - solves the problem.

Comment: thanks for the insight, very much appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your company use SharePoint?
I just created a web database relatively easily that is hosted on sharepoint.

You should be able to import your tables pretty easily.

Possibly relevant:
[Move Access Web Database to Another Sharepoint Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970422/move-access-web-database-to-another-sharepoint-site)

Comment: Actually, Sharepoint is a very good idea, if the OP's organization already uses Sharepoint, and if their Sharepoint admins are willing to publish the .mdb Access database.

Comment: I believe i am using IIS.  If i was to use sharepoint would you mean i would just have another database on the sharepoint that would sync with the one on our network.

Answer (score 0):

If you going to build a web interface, then you need to use web development tools.

You can of course adopt terminal services, and thus consume the application on an iPad or any device that supports remote desktop protocol (RDP).

And you can now “eliminate” the need for a RDP client since technology does exist that converts RDP to pure HTML5. Check out:

https://www.cybelesoft.com/thinfinity/remote-desktop/

In fact there is even an open source one here:

http://guac-dev.org/

The above will thus let you run existing Access applications in a browser – you need a server running remote desktop for this purpose.

As several mentioned, you can also adopt Access web publishing, but that choice does not support VBA, nor does it support existing forms etc. (you have to re-build your forms as access web forms and no conversion of existing forms exists).